# Runing Robot Framework Script From Python Library which Load cdll throwing error

Tags: python-2.7, shared-libraries, robotframework, .so

```
from ctypes import cdll
from time import sleep

class SDKLibrary(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        self.lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("sharedlibrary.so")
        self.sdk = self.lib.SDK_new()

    def Function(self):
        self.lib.Function1(self.sdk, 1, 2)


x = SDKLibrary()
x.Function() //This call from Python working fine
```

But when I'm trying to call from robot the Function its throwing an error with no arguments failed: OSError: sharedlibrary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your file structure looks like but I had this same issue when I put my robot test scripts in a different folder than my python libraries. I solved it by pre-pending an absolute file path to the C library.

```
def __init__(self): 
    self.lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(absolute/file/path/ + "sharedlibrary.so")
    self.sdk = self.lib.SDK_new()
```